# Senhor e Senhora com letra maiúscula ou minúscula?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, uso-de-palavras, pronomes, maiúsculas-e-minúsculas

Olá, eu tenho uma dúvida sobre o uso dos pronomes **'senhor'** e **'senhora'** no contexto militar. Eu jogo um simulador de Exército Brasileiro que tenta ser fiel a vida real e gostaria de saber se devo escrever o pronome **'Senhor'** com **'S'** maiúsculo ou minúsculo, o mesmo para o pronome **'Senhora'**.

Por exemplo: como devo utilizar em frases simples como *'Saudações, senhor', 'Olá, senhora, como está?', 'Bom dia, Senhor'.*

Devo usar a primeira letra em maiúsculo ou minúsculo para esses pronomes? Gostaria de entender qual é a forma gramaticalmente correta.

Answer (score 5):

**Em resumo**: a gramática sugere a inicial minúscula, mas é flexível, enquanto a deferência hierárquica e formalidade militares indicam a inicial **maiúscula**.

---

O [Acordo Ortográfico de 1990](https://www.volp-acl.pt/index.php/ortografia/texto-integral-do-ao90) determina, em sua "Base XIX – Das minúsculas e maiúsculas" o uso preferencial de minúsculas, com maiúsculas opcionais:

> 1.º A letra minúscula inicial é usada:
> [...] f) Nos axiónimos/[axiônimos](https://dicionario.priberam.org/axi%C3%B4nimo) e hagiónimos/[hagiônimos](https://dicionario.priberam.org/hagi%C3%B4nimo) (opcionalmente, neste caso, também com maiúscula): **senhor** doutor Joaquim da Silva [...]
> [...]
> 2.º A letra maiúscula inicial é usada:
> [...] i) Opcionalmente, em palavras usadas reverencialmente, [aulicamente](https://dicionario.priberam.org/aulicamente) ou hierarquicamente [...]

A preferência pela inicial minúscula em "senhor" é explicitada pela linguista Helena Figueira, escrevendo para o site da FLiP (Priberam), "[Dúvidas Linguísticas](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/456)":

> As formas de tratamento são usualmente grafadas em maiúsculas (ex.: Vossa Alteza), excepto quando se trata de pronomes pessoais ou de locuções como *o **senhor**, a senhorita* [...]

E o [Infoescola](https://www.infoescola.com/portugues/pronomes-de-tratamento/) também coloca:

> Quanto ao emprego de iniciais maiúsculas ou minúsculas nos pronomes de tratamento, há ainda um certo impasse, porém alguns gramáticos sugerem que se use letras **minúsculas** nos pronomes mais usuais ou comuns, tais quais: **senhor**, senhora, doutor, dona, dom, senhorita, professor, você. Já nos demais pronomes, menos usuais e mais formais, utiliza-se letras maiúsculas, como por exemplo: Vossa Senhoria, Vossa Excelência, Vossa Santidade, etc.

Mas fontes ligadas a órgãos militares determinam [1] o uso da maiúscula.

Por exemplo, a "Correspondência e Atos Oficiais do Comando da Aeronáutica" [NSCA 10-2/2019](https://www.sislaer.fab.mil.br/terminalcendoc/Acervo/Detalhe/4501?a=1&guid=1625875206454) grafa "**Senhor**", com maiúscula, assim como as [normas da Polícia Militar de Pernambuco](http://www2.pm.pe.gov.br/c/document_library/get_file?p_l_id=13029&folderId=2532474&name=DLFE-26107.pdf).

Para o caso específico de vocativos, mesmo instituições não militares, mas caracterizadas por uma maior formalidade, por vezes dão preferência ao uso da maiúscula. Um exemplo é o Superior Tribunal de Justiça, como se pode ver [1] em seu [Manual de padronização de textos do STJ](https://www.stj.jus.br/publicacaoinstitucional/index.php/Manual/author/proofGalleyFile/1014/948). Essa norma é compatível com a posição de Flávia Neves, que, no [Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/abreviacao-de-senhora-e-senhor/), embora determine a preferência pela minúscula, sugere o uso da maiúscula em documentos oficiais.

---

[1] É importante lembrar que tais fontes, embora relevantes para o uso dentro das instituições que as adotam, **não** são fontes fidedignas para o ortografia normativa *correta*. O Senado Federal Brasileiro, por exemplo, [determina](https://www12.senado.leg.br/manualdecomunicacao/estilos/abreviatura) o uso da abreviatura "sr.", que não se encontra em dicionários ou no [VOLP](https://volp-acl.pt/index.php/geral/abreviaturas), assim como das abreviaturas "KB" para quilobyte e "KHz" para quilo-hertz, com "K" maiúsculo, enquanto o símbolo convencional do prefixo *quilo*- do Sistema Internacional de Pesos e Medidas [é](https://dicionario.priberam.org/k) o "k" minúsculo.

Comment: e Senhor quando se refere a Pai, tio? "O Sr. está bem?"

Comment: @ClMend A menos que se deseje denotar especial reverência, a minúscula é [mais indicada](https://www.dicio.com.br/pronomes-de-tratamento/). Caso a abreviatura seja usada, contudo, a maior parte das fontes determina o uso da maiúscula ("Sr.", não "sr.").